# powershellでchmodコマンドが認識されない

Tags: powershell

windows10でファイルのパーミッション変更をしたく、chmodコマンドを入力したら認識されませんでした。

> chmod : 用語 'chmod' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されませ
> ん。名前が正しく記述されていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してくだ
> さい。

他に変更する方法、またはchmodが使えるようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか。
ご教授願います。

Comment: これではないでしょうか？[PowerShell　所有者と権限の変更方法](https://ryukiko0730.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/06/10/230000)

Comment: GitBashが入っていたのでそれでchmodを使用することもできました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod` は Linux 向けのコマンドなので、Windows 環境で使用することはできません。

Windows でファイルの所有者やアクセス権限をコマンドで変更するには、`takeown` や `icacls` コマンドを使用するようです。

**参考:**

- [Windowsでファイルの所有者を変更する（コマンドプロンプト編）](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0604/01/news021.html)
- [Windowsのicaclsコマンドでファイルの所有者を変更する](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1006/25/news094.html)